# issue when upgrading agic to 1.5.2

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress

As our aks relate to two different agw, when upgrading AGIC by helm, we got this error:

helm upgrade agic-ass application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure --version 1.5.1
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with update: IngressClass "azure-application-gateway" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "agic-ass"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "default"

how to fix it and upgrade AGIC to 1.5.1 by helm?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue, and the fix for me was to add `--reuse-values` to the Helm upgrade command.

Comment: but it seems got new error : helm upgrade agic-ass --reuse-values application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure --version 1.5.2               
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: ingress-azure/templates/ingressclass.yaml:1:14: executing "ingress-azure/templates/ingressclass.yaml" at <.Values.kubernetes.ingressClassResource.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reinstall instead of upgrading by adding new config as "ingressClassResource" into the helm-config.yaml , it works anyway.